# Are complex conjugates unique?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I'm trying to decide if a function $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\varphi(\alpha)=\bar{\alpha}$ is onto or one to one. I know it will be onto because every element in $\mathbb{C}$ has a complex conjugate, but I'm not sure if it will be one to one.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Suppose that $z = x + iy$ and $w = s + it$ satisfy $$\varphi(z) = \varphi(w)$$

That is, by definition of the conjugate, that

$$x - iy = s - it$$

or after some rearrangement

$$x - s = i (y - t)$$

How can a real number equal another real number times $i$?

---

Just as a comment on another part of your question, the fact that $\varphi$ is onto doesn't follow from the fact that every complex number *has* a conjugate. It follows from the fact that every complex number *is* a conjugate of something - in particular,

$$\overline{\overline{z}} = z$$

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Well, it can - but only in one very specific case.

Comment: Really? What's that? And isn't that the same statement since every complex number has a complex conjugate and the complex conjugate itself is a complex number?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops $0i = 0$ is the only time it works, and it's OK - that shows that $x - s = 0 \implies x = s$ and likewise for the other part. This shows that $z = w$.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Saying that every complex number has a complex conjugate just means that $\varphi$ is defined for all complex numbers. It doesn't actually prove that given $z$, there exists $w$ for which $\varphi(w) = z$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi^2=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb C}$. In general, if $f\circ g$ is onto, what can you say about $f$ and $g$? How about one-to-one instead of onto?